# WCF Message Size

Tags: wcf

Is there any way to test the size of a message before it is sent back to the client? I'd like to handle the maximum message size quota on the service side of things.

Comment: Can you provide more info about what you are trying to do? A message inspector might be sufficient but without knowing which message encoder is being used you won't know the exact size. Also this would be very expensive in memory and CPU as you would allocate a lot of memory and serialize the message twice.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a custom `MessageEncoder`, use it on the service side, and check an encoded message size inside it's `WriteMessage` methods.

Follow [this guide](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosfigueira/2011/11/08/wcf-extensibility-message-encoders) and override the methods in such a way:

```
public override ArraySegment<byte> WriteMessage(Message message, int maxMessageSize, BufferManager bufferManager, int messageOffset)
{
    var result = this.text.WriteMessage(message, maxMessageSize, bufferManager, messageOffset);

    // Encoded message check logic.
    Console.WriteLine("Message sent. Length=" + result.Count);

    return result;
}

public override void WriteMessage(Message message, Stream stream)
{
    var position = stream.Position;

    this.text.WriteMessage(message, stream);

    // Encoded message check logic.
    Console.WriteLine("Message sent. Length=" + (stream.Position - position));
}
```